# trouble with recursion in php

Tags: php, recursion

I cannot figure out why this function is not working.  Evertime I try to make the recursive call all I get is an IE page with a cannot display error message. I left // by the lines that is causing me the trouble.  I also tried the call without the $this-> and got an error function not recognized

```
private function insert($key, $current)    {     
    $newnode=new Node($key); 
    $parent=$this->root;
    if($this->root==null)  {  
        $this->root=$newnode;         
        return;   
    } else {
        if($newnode->data > $parent->data) {
            $parent=$parent->rightChild;
            $this->insert($key, $parent);//if I comment this line it 
                //work, but that make the function useless
        } else {
            echo "smaller ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005602/trouble-with-recursion-in-php (sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: Is the recursion condition ever NOT met? In other words is `$newnode->data > $parent->data` always true?

Comment: @Phil I LOL'ed enough that my 4 year old came to see what was up.

Comment: Please put braces around both your `if` and `else` blocks. Leaving them out leads to confusion and possibly incorrect control flow

Comment: can we see the rest of the code that is being covered here?

Comment: @Aaron I edited your code example to put the braces in, hope you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

The error is obviously an infinite recursive loop.

This is most probably due to the fact that you never use the `$current` argument.

You're always comparing the `$newnode->data` against `$this->root->data` which if greater once, will always be greater.

#### Update

Here's how I'd change it

```
private function insert($key, $current = null)
{
    $newnode = new Node($key);
    $parent = null === $current ? $this->root : $current;
    if (null === $parent) {
        $this->root = $newnode;
        return;
    }
    if ($newnode->data > $parent->data) {
        // same as before from here
```